# Horizontal navigation bar not working in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, navigation

My horizontal navigation bar is working fine with Chrome, Opera, Mozilla, even IE8 but it's not working on IE6.

Codes as follows:

### HTML part

```
<div id="mainNav" class="container">
  <div id="menuh">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="top_parent">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html" class="top_parent">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="why_us.html" class="top_parent">Why Us?</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="services.html" class="parent">What I can do for you</a></li>
          <!-- No need to anchor to [#ancService1] -->
          <li><a href="services.html#ancWhatyouget" class="parent">What you can get</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html#ancTestimonials" class="parent">Testimonials</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="free_resources.html" class="top_parent">Free Resources</a></li>
      <li><a href="how_much.html" class="top_parent">How Much?</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html" class="top_parent">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="register.html" class="top_parent">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS part

```
#mainNav {height: 30px;}

#menuh {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
}

#menuh a {
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
        white-space:nowrap;
    margin:0;
    padding: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid #036; 
    height: 24px;
}

#menuh a:visited, #menuh a:active {
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#menuh a.parent:link {
    color: white;
    background-color: #204988;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#menuh a.top_parent {
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 10px 15px 0 15px;
}
#menuh a.top_parent:hover {
    color: #8CBA01;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-image: url(../_images/img_nav.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#menuh a.parent {
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 7px 15px 0 15px;
}
#menuh a.parent:hover {
    color: #8CBA01;
    background-color: #036;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#menuh ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: auto;
}
#menuh li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;  
}

#menuh li li a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 140px;
}

#menuh ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:500;
    top:auto;
    display:none;
}

div#menuh li:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:100;
}

div#menuh li:hover ul ul,
div#menuh li li:hover ul ul
{display:none;}

div#menuh li:hover ul,
div#menuh li li:hover ul
{display:block;}
```

Any help would be great!
Thanks.

Comment: What's the issue you're seeing in IE6?

Comment: The problem is that the navigation bar (main & submenu) display is all messed up in IE6. Each indivudal link in the menu appears across the full width of the screen.

Comment: I just had this similar issue... ie6 is evil http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your style rules it's a little confusing what's going on, so I made a jsfiddle that should work, and it includes the jquery necessary to make the hover work on IE6 as well with one problem: the list sub-menu displays with the li horizontally - you'll have to figure out how to resolve that part yourself. I changed the markup and style rules applied to be more straightforward: http://jsfiddle.net/2p7cx/

Comment: Thanks heaps! But what does "li.over ul" does?

Comment: That's the style rule applied when the "over" class is added. The jquery adds the class on hover so that it will work on IE6 - but like I said, there's still an issue of it not displaying the sub-menu options vertically on IE6 (it should be, I just got too busy to figure out why) Also, in the jsfiddle, it looks like I repeated the li.over ul twice - that's just a typo.

Comment: Thanks Kinakuta. Great help!!

Answer (score 1):

Without you stating what your problem is, I'm not sure this is the cause, but the `:hover` pseudo-selector is only supported on the `a` tag in IE6.

Comment: Thanks Rfvgyhn. The problem is that the navigation bar display is all messed up in IE6. Each indivudal link in the menu appears across the full width of the screen. Submenu is missing. I'm not sure if the hover is a problem as I cannot even view the submenu on the page. The "container" that I specify doesn't seem to work either - the header and content are aligned left instead of center. But the footer alignment appears fine. Also, the display for login form at the top right corner is messed up too.

Answer (score 0):

@Rfvgyhn is correct. In IE6, `:hover` only works on `a` elements.

To remedy this and allow things like `div#menuh li:hover` to work, the easiest solution is to use a JavaScript fix:

Whatever:hover - http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html